# parseError, Syntax Error: Invalid Character on jquery Json query for Sharepoint

Tags: jquery, json, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to work with the project [found here](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/10/16/use-knockoutjs-in-sharepoint-2013-aspx/). My list has been configured similar to the list in the tutorial. It is not working for me.  I tracked the issue down to my JSON query.

I rewrote the JSON query to conform to the example found on the jQuery site.    When I execute the query, I get a failure with the error `parseError, Syntax Error: Invalid Character` on jQuery.

What would cause this error? This is my first time doing a JSON query.

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/ProductList", function() {
    alert("success"); 
}).done(function() {
    alert("second success");
}).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    alert("Request Failed: " + err);
}).always(function() {
    alert("complete");
});

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.complete(function() {
    alert( "second complete" );
});
```

Comment: From the error it sounds like the response coming back from that URL is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint url `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/ProductList"` refers to default list view page, it means are you not getting JSON-encoded data from the server.

You probably want REST endpoint for getting list items, in that case the url will look like this:

```
https://server/_api/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items
```

[More info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx)

**Example**

```
var listTitle = 'Tasks';  //set list title
var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items";

$.getJSON(requestUrl)
.done(function(items) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(items.value));  //print list items
}).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    console.log("Request Failed: " + error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  Now I am getting Not Acceptable as an error.   I noticed that I paste the URL http://wdwss116w/PP06852/Knockout/_api/lists/ getbytitle('ProductList')/items into FireFox, I am getting back XML and not JSON but the XML does not contain any data.

Comment: Please make sure the valid url is provided, for example, is `ProductList` a proper **title** of list?. Also a slash separator is missing, it should be: `http://wdwss116w/PP06852/Knockout/_api/lists/getbytitle('ProductList')/items`

Comment: The slashes are in there.   I think it was a cut and paste issue on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be an issue with the jQuery getJSON function when using it with sharepoint (I had thought I read a recent version of jquery boroke it).

What I did was to write the equivalent ajax call

var listTitle = 'ProductList';  //set list title

```
    var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items";               

    $.ajax({
                    url: requestUrl,
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                    success: function (data) {
                        // Returning the results
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
         });
```

Seems to work just fine.